# Omega Limit set containing only equilibria

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, vector-fields, nonlinear-dynamics

I am struggling to come to an answer the satisfies myself with the current problem.

I have a Lipschitz vector field, restricted to an hyperbox $\mathcal{B}= [a_i,b_i] \times[a_2,b_2]\times\dots\times[a_N,b_N]$. Such a set $\mathcal{B}$ is forward invariant, therefore for every initial condition $\xi \in \mathcal{B}$ the corresponding forward orbit is contained in a compact set. For my particular system I can show that:

1. For each $\xi$ the corresponding omega limit set $\omega(\xi)$ is made only of equilibria, i.e. every point in $\omega(\xi)$ is an equilibrium.

Is 1. enough to conclude that every solution converges to a certain, **single** equilibrium, even without assuming that the equilibria are isolated? If not, why not?

Comment: Do you mean there is a single equilibrium that is the omega limit of all the orbits or that each orbit has a single equilibrium in its omega limit? In the first case, the zero vector field would be a counter-example since each orbit is an equilibrium.

Comment: For each orbit, the omega limit set is made of equilibria (I don't know how many since I can not prove it). In particular, I can prove that every point in every (potentially different) omega limit set is an equilibrium. Can I conclude that each orbit converges to one of these equilibria in the respective omega limit set? Of course, each orbit has their own omega limit set (in general).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't. For simplicity the following example will be in dimension $N = 2$ but it can be generalized to higher dimensions and we take the box $[-1,1]^2$. First take a vector field with an equilibrium in the center and all the other orbits converging in a spiraling way to the periodic orbit in the circle of radius $\frac{1}{2}$ that we will denote by $C$, for instance, the following vector field in polar coordinates that we denote by $X$
$$
\begin{cases}
 r' = \left( \frac{1}{4}r-r^3\right)\\
\theta' = 1
\end{cases} 
$$
Here orbits starting from $p$ with $\|p\| > \frac{1}{2}$ have their norm decreasing and converges to $C$ with a spinning motion.
Now the key is using a bump function. Take $\varphi \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ of class $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ such that
$$
\varphi(p) 
\begin{cases}
  = 0, \ \text{if} \ \|p\| \leq \frac{1}{2} \ \text{or} \  \frac{3}{4} \leq \|p\|\\
>0,  \text{if} \ \frac{1}{2} < \|p\| < \frac{3}{4} 
\end{cases}
$$
and consider the field $Y = \varphi X$. Notice that outside the annulus $A = \{ p \in \mathbb{R}^2  : \frac{1}{2} < \|p\| < \frac{3}{4} \}$ all orbits are equilibriums, in particular the box is invariant. Also, since $Y$ is smooth in a compact set, it is Lipschitz. Now, all the orbits that start in the annulus $A$ converge to the circle $C$ in a spiraling (slower) way, so their omega limit set is the entire circle, but it is now full of equilibriums since the vector field on it is now $0$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I get it! For the case in which the equilibria are isolated, instead the convergence holds? SHould I open another question for that?

Comment: @giangian There's a result that states that if the omega limit of an orbit is compact, then it is connected. Here's a post on MSE talking about it: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/848884/compact-omega-limit-set-rightarrow-connected. In your case, the omega limit set is always compact, therefore connected, which implies that it cannot be discrete if it has more than one point.

Comment: Yes! That is the result I was referring to, to me is known as the Birkhoff theorem, thank you :)